# How to count how many times document was downloaded in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in my Firestore Database with posts. Each post has some comments as a document in the collection `comments` in the main post document (screenshot)[image]

In my Android app when I click on the post item I go to PostDetail screen and there I download comments.
I want to increment the value of `timesViewed` for each comment which has been downloaded and displayed.

Is it possible to do that? I want to do that in the most efficient way. I don't want to increment every single comment manually by sending a request timesViewed++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to increment the value of `timesViewed` for each comment which has been downloaded and displayed.

If you're looking for something that does that automatically, please note that there is nothing built-in.

> Is it possible to do that?

Yes, but you should implement your own mechanism.

> I don't want to increment every single comment manually by sending a request timesViewed++.

Unfortunately, there is no other way. However, it is very easy to implement. You can use [FieldValue.increment(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61318780/what-is-the-recommended-way-of-saving-durations-in-firestore).

Comment: Such a mechanism extremely increases my billable metrics and usage in Firebase right?  1 FieldValue.increment() = 1 request to Firebase ?

Comment: Yes, it does and that's correct. When you increment that field, you have to pay one document write.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer. I guess I have to give up this idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, such a feature does not exist in the RealtimeDatabase firebase and firestore to automatically increase a field.
But you can create a counter and retrieve the counter every time onResponse () or onComplete and increase it by 1, which is not recommended for 2 reasons.

1. Generates extra traffic, especially if the number of users is large
2. It is not reliable because someone can intentionally increase it

But if you do not mind a lot of traffic and you insist on doing so, do not forget to set rules in the firebase console to control the incremental frequency.