# How do I get the number of subcollectors in Firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a whiteboard app using Flutter and Firestore.
This whiteboard app creates a room first, then creates pages, and then draws inside the page.

Firestore has the following configuration:

[image]

I need to be able to get the number of subcollections in Firestore to get the number of pages.

How do I get the number of these subcollections(pages)?

Comment: Is room a document and the pages are subcollections of the document? Did I get that right?

Comment: Oh, they're both collectors and there's a document in between. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get all collection from one doc in dart.

> Retrieving a list of collections is not possible with the mobile/web client libraries. You should only look up collection names as part of administrative tasks in trusted server environments. If you find that you need this capability in the mobile/web client libraries, consider restructuring your data so that subcollection names are predictable.

[Here is the document link.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document)

Answer (score 1):

There is no function that can return the number of sub-collections that exist within a document. If you need such a count, you need to create this mechanism yourself. But it's pretty simple, you can create a document in which you can [increment/decrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61318780/what-is-the-recommended-way-of-saving-durations-in-firestore) a numeric value, each time a new sub-collection is added or deleted from the document.